# Difference between rng.RefersToRange.Parent.Name and rng.Parent.Name

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through named ranges of my workbook and check if they are in a specific Worksheet and then do something to it. Found a suggestion to use something like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Name
Set ws = somews
For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If rng.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = somews.Name Then 
        'do stuff
    End If
Next rng
```

At the beginning that worked fine. Now i have a problem. Somebody else uses this workbook as well and i don't know what they did. The workbook has a new sheet with named ranges, which are identical to some of my ranges in `somews`, but they refer to some outside source. I guess they were coping stuff between workbooks. The scope of my ranges is for entire workbook and the scope for those new ranges in only for that new sheet. I knew this would happen and that is why i needed this code.

This code breaks now. Because if `rng` is form the new sheet `rng.RefersToRange.Parent.Name` still returns the name of my sheet instead of the new sheet. So the `If` statement gets executed, but with wrong range. If i however use `rng.Parent.Name` i get the correct name.

What is the difference here? When should i use one and when the other? Is there a better way?

Comment: One is for a range, like Range("a1:A10") `RefersToRange` is the range that a name is for.  So if A1:A10 was named "Data" then `Names("Data").RefersToRange` would be A1:a10, so `Range("a1:A10").parent` is the same as `Names("Data").RefersToRange.parent`

Comment: Thx, i get it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.RefersToRange` is not a member of a [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) Object. It is a member of a [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name) Object.

The `.RefersToRange` object is how you would access the `Range` Object that is associated with the `Name` Object. Once you have a `Range` Object, the `.Parent` property will return the [Worksheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet) Object that the range belongs to. The `.Name` property will return the name of the worksheet.

So if `rng` is a Name Object, `rng.RefersToRange.Parent.Name` returns the name of the worksheet that contains the range that the name is associated with.

On the other side `rng.Parent.Name` doesn't go through the range, and is therefore less specific about which name it returns. The `.Parent` property is applied to the `Name` Object, which can refer to either a worksheet or the workbook. So depending on how the scope was defined when the `Name` Object was created, the `.Parent.Name` will return the name of either a single Worksheet or the Workbook.

Comment: I still don't understand, why in my case `rng.RefersToRange.Parent.Name` returns wrong sheet name?

Comment: @Ale The name returned should be the same as the worksheet name in the range's address. You can check the addresses of the Named Ranges using the Name Manager.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding between us. I have myRangeName on Sheet1 with scope workbook and i also have myRangeName on Sheet2 with scope Sheet2. When i loop through names `rng.RefersToRange.Parent.Name` returns Sheet1 for myRangeName on Sheet2 with scope Sheet2. But it supposed to return Sheet2. If i use `rng.Parent.Name` instead, i get Sheet2.

Comment: Oh, i think i understand now, Correct me if i'm wrong. myRangeName on Sheet2 with scope Sheet2 refers to a range in another workbook on a Worksheet with name Sheet1. That's why `rng.RefersToRange.Parent.Name` returns Sheet1 and not Sheet2. So i need to use `rng.Parent.Name` in my case.

Comment: @Ale As far as I know, its not possible to use Named Ranges across workbooks. Each workbook only tracks Names that were defined within that workbook. So if you have a library of Named Ranges and you want to find a similar range but in a second workbook, you can't just pass the range over because it belongs to a sheet from a different workbook but you can use the address to recreate the range like `NewWorkbook.Worksheets("New").Range(rng.RefersToRange.Address)`

Comment: Thx, chatting with you helped me to understand and find out that the problem was not this part of the code, but right before that. I forgot to reset 1 variable and it was using the previous value.